# Trigger CI Build only on changes to subfolder in VSTS (was TFS Online), using Git

Tags: git, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Git repo with two subfolders in Visual Studio Team Services. One is HelloWorld, the other ST. The path shows as this on my local folder.

root
  /HelloWorld
      /HelloWorld
  /ST

Under HelloWorld is a C# app. Under ST is a basic set of DB scripts.

I want to build with CI each of these separately. I have a build for HelloWorld and one for ST, each working independently. If I commit changes with git and push, the builds run successfully. Meaning, if I commit a C# change from VS, the ST database build will run, then the c#, VS solution build runs.
If I commit and push a db change, same thing. Both builds run.

However, if I use the new path filters in VSTS, and add a filter for the ST build with either of these:

- include "ST"
- exclude "HelloWorld"

And commit a change in either folder, the ST build will not run.

Likewise, if I add a filter to the HelloWorld build, include or exclude, that build will not run.

I've tried paths like:

- /HelloWorld
- HelloWorld/*
- HelloWorld/HelloWorld
- HelloWorld/HelloWorld/*
- H*
- /H*

A few more combinations, to either build. If I use any path filter, things won't trigger a build. A manual build works fine, no matter what the filters.

Am I missing something or are path filters broken?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure the folder structure of your project in TFS/VSTS, so I create a sample project for your reference, following is the folder structure:
[image]

The build will be triggered when there is change pushed into the fist "HelloWorld" folder and the change pushed into "ST" folder will not trigger the build with following settings:
[image]

The build will be only triggered when there is change pushed into "ST" folder:
[image]

Please check your folder structure from the "Code" tab first and then update the setting of your build definition.

Comment: Does "include: /HelloWorld" capture changes to subfolders as well and if not what's the proper syntax?

Comment: @aloneguid Yes, it capture the changes to sub folders.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to exclude "merge commit" from triggering the build? Often merge commits are outside of subfolder changes.

Comment: still doesn't work, changes are not triggering builds

Answer (score 0):

This had been a issue , refer to this link for details: [CI Builds may not trigger as expected.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2847213) Try to check if your build definition is impacted, **verify the definition through the history tab**.

Moreover, this issue has been fixed in 27 June.

> *Final Update: Monday, 27 June 2016 22:53 UTC*
>
> The hotfix deployment completed on 27 June 2016 21:26 UTC and we have
>   verified that we can no longer reproduce the issue. We understand that
>   customers rely on VS Team Services as a critical service and apologize
>   for any impact this incident caused.
>
> *Sincerely, Arvin*

Comment: What does "verify the definition through the history tab" mean? I have builds that work if I manually queue them, or I remove path filters. As soon as I add a path filter, the build doesn't work.

The link you mention is slightly different. I don't have builds for the entire repo. I have two subfolders, each with a diff project. I want builds for either project to work, independently.

In terms of your update, I'm not sure what this is from, but as of July18, things are still broken. I set up new builds on July 16, with a new project (hence HelloWorld) and the path filters are not working.